# How to share common dependencies between multiple gradle projects?

Tags: java, git, gradle, kotlin

I have two microservices written in Kotlin, they share a great deal of code and dependencies.

For sharing code, I have a git submodule repo setup, which is essentially a package that is common to all my microservices. I can have one microservice open in my IDE, push the common code to the git submodule and go and open the other project and simply pull and my common changes appear in this project as well.

However, I'm not sure how to declare dependencies common to all projects. The project is small and nimble enough that right now

- I want the entire organization to be on ONE kotlin version
- And the same version of all the shared frameworks between microservices (Same version of Ktor, same Exposed, same everything)

So, the cost of going out of sync would actually be greater than staying in sync (since we're small right now).

Here's an example dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version"
}
```

Now I want to share this between multiple projects. I want to update it once, say in a file under `coreModule/dependencies.gradle` and have it update in all projects all at once (e.g: Using a common gradle file in the core module itself)

I want to share the following lines

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version"
```

So that my dependencies block looks like this in BOTH projects

```
dependencies {
    commonDependencies()
    // .. microservice specific dependencies
}
```

What I need help with is defining the commonDependencies block such that it can be used within the dependencies blocks of both projects. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

- I would like to keep using git submodules only, since I find that far faster than managing the headache of pushing/pulling from a maven repo or managing JARs and all that comes with it. Happy to change my opinion if anyone knows of a better way though :)